# Is there a way to use the APIs of online streaming apps (Gaana/Saavn/Wync Music/Spotify/Google Music) to play songs directly from another app?

Tags: java, android, http, cloud

I want to create an Android app which can play songs from cloud (using Saavn/Google Music/ Hungama/Gaana/Spotify/SoundCloud etc.) using some APIs or intents. Is there any way to do that?

I already tried by passing as an intent_action_media_play_from_search from my app but that doesn't play song directly through the streaming app and it shows ambiguous screen.

And in google music it plays some random radio corresponding that.

```
        try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);

                /*                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                        "com.google.android.music",
                        "com.google.android.music.ui.search.VoiceActionsActivity"));*/


                //intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Song_name");                   

                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Song_name");
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
```

I expect it to play the searched song directly or if possible using some APIs, I may receive the ambiguous results and then play with some particular id.